# txtファイルの文字コードがUTF-8BOM無しか否かを確定で判定する方法はありますか。

Tags: 文字コード

支給ファイルをAccessのマクロで加工して自動出力する手順の作業があります。

この支給ファイルがUTF-8BOM無しか否かを何らかの方法で機械的かつ確定で判定させる方法はありますか？
NotePad++や秀丸エディタなど表示する際の文字コードを変更することで目視で化けているか判定する方法はありますが、手動の作業となってしまいますので現状これを自動化できるかどうか探しています。

▼下記記事を発見したのでまずは求める差異の判定ができるか確認してきます。
およそできそうな感じでした。
https://popozure.info/20190515/14201

Comment: いったんバイナリモードでファイルを開いて先頭4バイトを読み込めば確認出来るのでは？ [VBAでバイナリファイルを読み込む（一括、1バイト、指定バイト）](https://vbabeginner.net/read-binary-file/), [Open ステートメント](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/open-statement), [バイト順マーク - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E9%A0%86%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF)

Comment: 判定ツールを作って、その結果をもとにバッチファイルなり PowerShell なりでに処理を分けたい、ってことでしょうか？　判定だけならファイルの先頭数バイトを読むだけです。

Comment: メッセージありがとうございます。単に判定だけを想定しています。先頭バイトチェックで対応できるか確認してみます。

Comment: やっぱりよくわかりません。文字コードが期待に反していた場合にどうするのでしょうか？（Accessのマクロが確実にUTF-8BOM無しを出力した方が建設的なような？） ちなみに「文字コードを推測」ではなく「UTF-8BOM無しであること」を確認したいのであれば先頭だけでなくファイル全体を確認すべきとは思います。

Comment: 一応、もしUTF-8BOM無し以外の状態であることが発覚した場合はその一式の作業をゼロからやり直す＋支給データの不備を確認する以外に回避する方法がないのが現状です。ただなぜこのような事態になっているかといえば、前任者が不用意な失敗をして納品し、先方から是正命令が下ったために不要なチェック作業が発生して以降、チェック作業に含まれている次第です。現在は元の失敗箇所も含めて大幅に自動化されているため、そもそも論としてこのチェック作業自体不要ではあるのですが、やらざるをえない上からの圧力があるので検討不要です。自分はそのような無駄作業に手作業の時間を割きたくないということと、自分が手作業をすると高確率で失敗する人間なので自分の手より自分のプログラムの腕を信頼しているためです。